Как в swagger загружать картинки?
Как в swagger загружать картинки?
У меня есть код на django для создания объявления товара в котором присутствуют картинки, как в swagger можно подгружать картинки?
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Сериализатор для модели Product."""
    image = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        """Метакласс для указания модели и полей для сериализации."""

        model = Product
        fields = (
            "id",
            "title",
            "description",
            "category",
            "price",
            "time_period",
            "address",
            "deposit",
            "author",
            "image",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images = validated_data.pop("image")
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Получаем изображения
        for img in images:
            ProductImages.objects.create(product=product, image=img)
        return product

@extend_schema(
    tags=["Продукты"],
    methods=["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
)
@extend_schema_view(
    get=extend_schema(
        summary="Получение списка продуктов",
    ),
    post=extend_schema(
        summary="Добавление продукта",
    ),
    patch=extend_schema(
        summary="Изменение продукта",
    ),
    delete=extend_schema(
        summary="Удаление продукта",
    ),
)
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Класс для работы с моделью Product."""

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    http_method_names = ["get", "post", "patch", "delete"]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)


